# Read xml file using pd.read_xml with special characters in tags

Tags: pandas, xml

I would like to read an XML file with Umlauts in the tags using `read_xml()`, but I keep getting an error message.

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

f = io.StringIO("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Erzeugt durch 4D Anwendung-->
<Root>
  <r1_Belegzeile>
    <ID>65377</ID>
    <Belegtext>ABCABCABC</Belegtext>
    <Belegkürzel>ABC</Belegkürzel>
  </r1_Belegzeile>
  <r1_Belegzeile>
    <ID>65377</ID>
    <Belegtext>EFGEFGEFG</Belegtext>
    <Belegkürzel>EFG</Belegkürzel>
  </r1_Belegzeile>
</Root>
""")

df = pd.read_xml(f)
```

yields

```
XMLSyntaxError: error parsing attribute name, line 5, column 12
```

I tried adding `encoding="ISO-8859-1"` to `read_xml`, but that did not help. The offending character is the "ü" in "Belegkürzel".

One solution would be to globally replace all of the umlauts in the file, but maybe I can circumvent this.

Changing the parser to `parser="etree"` only changes the error message to `ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 5, column 11`.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

So far the only way I have found was to translate the umlauts and then read the result:

```
xml = f.read().translate(str.maketrans({"ä": "ae", "ö": "oe", "ü": "ue"}))

df = pd.read_xml(xml)
```

which yields:

```
|    |    ID | Belegtext   | Belegkuerzel   |
|---:|------:|:------------|:---------------|
|  0 | 65377 | ABCABCABC   | ABC            |
|  1 | 65377 | EFGEFGEFG   | EFG            |
```